# How to read line by line text data from gzipped text file using NIO?

Tags: java, io, gzip, nio

This is my code:
(zipped file contains text file)

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);            
try {
      ReadableByteChannel gzc = Channels.newChannel(new GZIPInputStream(Channels.newInputStream( Channels.newChannel( new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\111.gz")))));

      gzc.read(buffer);                        
}
```

Comment: It is worth nothing that this is highly unlikely to be simpler or more efficient that using plain IO.  I would only do this if you have to support a library which only takes NIO.

Comment: By efficiency, I mean performance.  The main bottle neck is the compression/decompression and using extra layers/wrappers is likely to make it slightly slower (though not by much by comparison)  Using direct ByteBuffer is faster when it *reduces* the amount of copies around the system.

Comment: That is a good idea.  I would test first how fast you can read the data without breaking into lines as this is simpler.  Only if this is promising would I test how fast it is with reading line by line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will also depend on the buffer size. You might want to wrap a BufferedInputStream() into the mix, with a large buffer (eg !MB), to get a lot of blocks from the disk at once.